# how to change the background color of the current cursor position in assembly

Tags: assembly, colors, background, cursor

I am coding in low-level assembly (16 bit) and I want the user to be able to change the background color in a "paint" like program. I already have everything working like, WASD and color (you make a cursor-position green) with space, code:

```
mov ah, 09h
mov bl, 00100101b
mov cx, 1d
int 10h
```

But when I want to change it back with 'x' or 'q' code:

```
mov ah, 09h
mov bh, 0
mov bl, 00010000b
mov cx, 1d
int 10h
```

It changes the background color to blue. But it also puts a 'x' or a 'q' on that block too!

How can I make it to only make the background color to blue (and cursor to black still) and NOT place a 'x' or a 'q' (using x or q characters)?

Comment: Using int 10h, ah=9 is going to write the character from ah to the current position using the attribute specified by bl.  If you don't want to write 'x' or 'q', put a different value in ah.  For example you could use a space (mov ah, ' ').  Or perhaps you want to read the existing character and re-write it using the new color.  int 10, ah=8 can be used to read the existing values.  Note that using int 10 isn't known for its performance.  For better performance, a lot of DOS programs read/wrote directly to video memory.

Comment: thanks alot.... but how do i read/write directly to video memory ( sorry if i sound like a noob :) )

Comment: Everybody is a noob at some point.  There are libraries that you can use, but if you want to read some docs, how about http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0089.HTM

Comment: @YoranJansen This code can't work because `mov ah,''` is wrong! The character ('') goes in the `AL` register and the function number (09h) goes in the `AH` register. (It's fair to say that David Wohlferd gave you the bad example!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov ah, 09h
mov bh, 0
mov bl, 00010000b
mov cx, 1d
int 10h
```

This snippet will write **whatever character is in `AL` register** to the screen! On the text video screen it will show a blue background color and a black foreground color.

In order to only change the background color you need to first read what's on screen. Use BIOS function 08h for that purpose:

```
mov  bh, 0         ;Display page
mov  ah, 08h
int  10h           ;Gives character in AL (keep it!), and attribute in AH
mov  bl, 00010000b ;Blue background
and  ah, 15        ;Keep existing foreground color in low nibble
or   bl, ah        ;Combine in new attribute byte
mov  cx, 1
mov  ah, 09h
int  10h
```